# Scrolling a ListView to a position after cursor loads

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a ListView, and I want the ListView to maintain its scroll position when the fragment is saved and restored. Usually this is easy, just call ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() when saving and ListView.setSelection() (ListView.setSelectionFromTop() if you want to get fancy) when restoring.

However, I'm using loaders, and my ListView isn't fully populated when the activity starts. If I setSelection() during onActivityCreated() the list won't have anything to scroll to yet, and the call will be ignored.

I'm getting around this now by posting the scroll for sometime in the future, but this definitely isn't ideal. I'd prefer for it to scroll right as the data finishes loading. I'm almost doing that here, but swapCursor() doesn't refresh, it just schedules an invalidation for the future.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    if (savedScrollPosition != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loaded and scrolling to " + savedScrollPosition);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.setSelection(savedScrollPosition);
                savedScrollPosition = null;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Do you know of any way of scrolling the ListView right as the ListView finishes populating with data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(savedScrollPosition);
            savedScrollPosition = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where did you add this code?  Can you explain a little more - I'm not sure I understand what is going on here.

Comment: You can put this code at a place where you have access to the `savedScrollPosition`. For better understanding, you can create a demo with listview, and then add this code in `onCreate()` (you should populate the listview) to see how you can scroll to a listview's position. Basically, the runnable created here calls the superclass `View`'s `post` which then adds it to the message queue and dispatched by `Looper`.