# ItemView in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have in a layout with a ListView. In onCreate() I set Adapter to the ListView, to show the list, this work fine.

But I try to get access to a ItemView of the listview like this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679284/1149815

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
    listView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater()));

    int wantedPosition = 1; 
    int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same as child #0
    int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;

    if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= listView.getChildCount()) {
      Log.w("--", "Unable to get view");
    }

    View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);

    Log.i("--","" +( wantedView == null) + "");
}}
```

I need access to wantedView, can someone help me?

LogCat says:

--"Unable to get view

-- true

Thanx

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Can you plz post the logcat details?

Comment: The Problem is wantedView is null

Answer (score 0):

move your code starting with int wantedPosition = 1 and below to the Runnable that you post after setting the adapter: listview.post(runnable)

Comment: leave starting code in onCreate up to listView.setAdapter(), the rest of the code put in some Runnable and after listView.setAdapter() call listview.post(runnable)

Comment: Perhaps you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304055/1149815 Thanx... I will try it